# Meaning of "serious student"

Tags: meaning

What are the  same meaning and opposite meaning of  **serious student**?

> I found the book tittled **A handbook for serious students**.
>
> Does it means **hard-working students** or **thoughtful students?**

Answer (score 2):

***Serious*** in the sense of  ***[serious-minded](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/serious-minded)***:

> - characterized by seriousness of intention, purpose, thought, etc.; earnest.

***[Serious studet](https://www.google.it/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=serious%20student)*** is  sort of idiomatic expression,(see  [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=serious%20student%2C%20serious%20students&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cserious%20student%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cserious%20students%3B%2Cc0)) that is often used in school/academinc contexts.

Comment: How can u define it?

Comment: @learner - a student who is really interested and involved  in his studies, dedicated to learning.

Answer (score 2):

> serious

has the meaning of focussed, devoted, dedicated

> a *serious* student

is one who is hard-working and diligently studies possibly to the exclusion of everything else

> a *serious* girlfriend / boyfriend

is a partner in a relationship which is not casual and to whom one is devoted

> a *serious* piece of work

is an idiom which can be used to describe a complex object either by construction, engineering, or understanding

> That figure plane is a *serious* piece of work.